# How to use OpenSSL in network kernel extension?

Tags: c, macos, openssl, kernel, kernel-extension

I'm building a network kernel extension which requires the OpenSSL library by including a few headers in some of my project files.

The problem is that OpenSSL includes `stdlib.h` (among other headers) which all throw errors (*File not found*). Same happens if I include `stdlib.h` in a project file.

I guess that's due to the fact that they are not available in the kernel. 
So, how do I include them? What am I missing?

Otherwise, how do I include CommonCrypto or any crypto library in the kernel?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSL and CommonCrypto are userspace libraries. They are not available in the kernel.

Some parts of CoreCrypto are available in the kernel under `<libkern/crypto/…>` and `<corecrypto/…>`. Generally speaking, however, this is limited to cryptographic primitives (AES, RSA, SHA, etc), not higher-level tools like X509 certificate parsing, key exchange algorithms, or TLS.

Comment: What I am looking for are AES, HKDF, HMAC and ECDHE but only `sha1.h` and `md5.h` are available under `libkern/crypto`. `corecrypto` seems not to be available on my machine by default but I found the source code [here](https://developer.apple.com/security/) but I don't really know how I make the library available for me to include in a kext. Would you help me please?

Comment: should I handle encryption/decryption in user space?

Comment: Hard to say for sure without knowing your application, but yes -- if you have a choice, crypto should happen in userspace. The less code that ends up running in the kernel, the better.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications!